# Catching exception from a specialized method

Tags: c++, templates, exception, c++11

Let's consider the following three files.

**tclass.h:**

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template<typename rt>
class tclass
{
public:
    void wrapper()
    {
        //Storage is empty
        for(auto it:storage)
        {
        }

        try
        {
            thrower();
        }
        catch(...)
        {
            std::cout << "Catch in wrapper\n";
        }
    }

private:
    void thrower(){}
    std::vector<int> storage;
};
```

**spec.cpp:**

```cpp
#include "tclass.h"

//The exact type does not matter here, we just need to call the specialized method.
template<>
void tclass<long double>::thrower()
{
    //Again, the exception may have any type.
    throw (double)2;
}
```

**main.cpp:**

```cpp
#include "tclass.h"
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    tclass<long double> foo;
    try
    {
        foo.wrapper();
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        std::cerr << "Catch in main\n";
        return 4;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I use Linux x64, gcc 4.7.2, the files are compiled with this command:

`g++ --std=c++11 *.cpp`

First test: if we run the program above, it says:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'double'
Aborted
```

Second test: if we comment `for(auto it:storage)` in the `tclass.h` file, the program will catch the exception in `main` function. <s>WAT</s>Why? Is it a stack corruption caused by an attempt to iterate over the empty vector?

Third test: lets uncomment back the `for(auto it:storage)` line and move the method specialization from `spec.cpp` to `main.cpp`. Then the exception is caught in `wrapper`. How is it possible and why does possible memory corruption not affect this case?

I also tried to compile it with different optimization levels and with `-g`, but results were the same.

Then I tried it on Windows 7 x64, VS2012 express, compiling with x64 version of cl.exe with no extra command line arguments. At the first test this program produced no output, so I think it just crashed silently, so the result is similar with Linux version. For the second test it produced no output again, so result is different from Linux. For the third test the result was similar with Linux result.

Are there any errors in this code so they can lead to such behavior? May the results of the first test be caused by possible bug in compilers?

Comment: How and where do you declare and define the template specialization?

Comment: @Juraj I specialize only the `thrower` method, which is in `spec.cpp`. Do I need to specialize anything else to make it work properly?

Comment: @Juraj Got it! Surely there is no need to specialize whole class, but the solution is to add declaration (i.e. `template<> void tclass<long double>::thrower();`) to the header. It works for both 03 and 11. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your code, I have with gcc 4.7.1:

`spec.cpp:6: multiple definition of 'tclass<long double>::thrower()'`

You may correct your code by declaring the specialization in your .h as:

`template<> void tclass<long double>::thrower();`